# Broadcasting through UDP

Tags: networking, udp, broadcast, multicast

I've been tasked with creating a video forwarding software that is supposed to take  a H.264 streaming MPEG video that is transmitted through UDP broadcast and redistribute it via multicast.

I understand the basic ideas behind broadcast and multicast, but I just don't understand what IP addresses I'm supposed to use. I know that multicast addresses are reserved from 224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255 so does that mean I can just pick any address in that range?

On a side note, I've been trying to create a broadcast stream with VLC that I can use simulate the UDP broadcast coming in and I've been able to this successfully using localhost (127.0.0.1) to stream to, but I'm not sure if that's what I want/ need. Is there a way I can stream to some other IP address? I tried streaming to the IP address of my computer, but I was not able to view the stream from the other end. The error was "cannot open socket".

Comment: For multicast, you normally use something in the Organization-local Scope (`239.0.0.0/8`) that you coordinate within your organization to keep from stepping on other multicast groups. IANA maintains the _[IPv4 Multicast Address Space Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml)_. Also, multicast routing is _very_ different than unicast routing, and you must configure that if you need to route multicast.